# With TestCafe Selector, How to verify the text of the selected item in a &lt;select&gt;?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm using TestCafe 1.8.1 and have a slightly different case than the documentation at https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/test-select-elements.html - my problem is that the example assumes the `value` of an `<option>` and its text content will be the same, and in my case, the `value` is a very unpredictable value.

I can select an item in the dropdown without trouble, using `.withText(value)` to filter the options, and `.click(item)` to select it.  However, my app then refreshes the page, and ought to re-select the relevant item as it loads up.  This is not working and I want to test for it.

So I might have options in the select like:

```
<select id="foo">
  <option value="1234">100x100</option>
  <option value="5432">200x100</option>
  <option value="9999">100x200</option>
</select>
```

Obviously, if I test with `.expect(citySelect.value).eql('London');` as in the docs it'll fail because the values are nothing like the text content e.g. having clicked '200x100' in the dropdown the value becomes "5432".

Do I need to use a `ClientFunction` to get the text of the selected item?  I understand it's quite awkward passing data into a ClientFunction, would I need to pass the `id` of the select so the ClientFunction can `getElementById` to find the select and retrieve it's selected option's text content? It all sounds like the wrong way to be doing things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the following example that uses `ClientFunction` API to obtain an `option` value:

```js
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Fixture 1`
    .page `https://kys0l.csb.app/`;

test('Test 1', async t => {
    const selector = Selector('select');

    const getValue = ClientFunction((index) => {
            const select = selector();

            return select.options[index].value;
    }, { dependencies: { selector } });

    await t
        .expect(getValue(0)).eql('1234')
        .expect(getValue(1)).eql('5432')
        .expect(getValue(2)).eql('9999');
});
```

See also: [Obtain Client-Side Info](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/obtain-client-side-info.html).

Comment: Thank you @aleks-pro, this helped. My `ClientFunction` can take a Selector as its argument, so:  `const getValue = ClientFunction((selector) => {
    const select = selector();
    return select.options[select.selectedIndex].innerText;
});` .. then in the test script, `const sel:Selector = Selector('select#theselect'); ... let value = await getValue(sel);`

Answer (score 1):

Try using

`.expect(citySelect.innertext).eql('London');`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. I find that in Chrome as normal, asking for `innerText` of a `<select>` gives a long string of all option values.  From a TestCafe test, `await dropdown.innerText` always seems to return an empty string. Verified experimentally on the docs test with `console.log('Test: (' + await citySelect.innerText + ')');` as the last line of the test, which prints `Test: ()`

Comment: Hmm, weird.  In my experiment above on the simple test from the docs, I got empty string, and in my own test I also saw empty.  Now I'm running the test suite against production, I'm seeing `innerText` giving the long list of all the `<option>` texts.  Not sure what's going on.. but still, it's not the value I'm looking for :)